# Cannot move out because of borrowing

Tags: rust, ownership

I have the following MWE:

```rust
use rusqlite::{Connection, Transaction };

fn main() {
    let mut cn: Connection = Connection::open_in_memory().unwrap();
    let tx: Transaction = cn.transaction().unwrap();

    let mut stmt = tx.prepare("
        INSERT INTO mytable (data) VALUES(1)
    ").unwrap();
    stmt.execute([]).unwrap();

    tx.commit().unwrap();
}
```

In my IDE (vscode), it shows:

`tx.prepare` shows an error

> borrow of `tx` occurs here

`tx.commit();` shows an error

> cannot move out of `tx` because it is borrowed

Signature :

```rust
 pub fn prepare(&self, sql: &str) -> Result<Statement<'_>> {
        self.db.borrow_mut().prepare(self, sql)
 }
 ...
 #[inline]
 pub fn commit(mut self) -> Result<()> {
     self.commit_()
 }
```

I dont understand why thoses errors are shown.

- After `tx.prepare` borrows, what is ownership the `Transaction` created and assigned to `tx` ?
- Is `tx` still the owner of the `Transaction` ?
- When `tx.commit()` is called, `Transaction` shoud be owned by `tx` and be safe to be moved when calling `.commit()`, no ?

Also, scoping the `tx.prepare` fixes those errors

```rust
use rusqlite::{Connection, Transaction };

fn main() {
    let mut cn: Connection = Connection::open_in_memory().unwrap();
    let tx: Transaction = cn.transaction().unwrap();
    {
        let mut stmt = tx.prepare("
            INSERT INTO mytable (data) VALUES(1)
        ").unwrap();
        stmt.execute([]).unwrap();
    }
    tx.commit().unwrap();
}
```

Thank you!

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5bd0394395c9da5a34161c382dc730b2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After `tx.prepare` borrows, what is ownership the `Transaction` created and assigned to `tx` ?

Not sure I understand what you're asking. A borrow doesn't change ownership, it borrows *from* the owner. So `tx` owns the transaction object, `stmt` borrows it, and thus the ownership can not change.

> Is tx still the owner of the Transaction ?

Yes.

> When `tx.commit()` is called, Transaction shoud be owned by tx and be safe to be moved when calling `.commit()`, no ?

In most cases yes, the problem here is that `Statement` is not a "trivial" type, it implements `Drop` which means it will (by default) live until the end of its [drop scope](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#drop-scopes) unless it is explicitly dropped (e.g. by calling `drop(stmt)`). This, then, compiles with `Transaction::commit` as you can't move out of an "active borrow".

You can observe this behaviour simply by mounting a type-scheme which matches that of Rusqlite: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=32532b41467706d0d80756525a0f43fe

As is the code compiles, but if you uncomment line 24 (`impl Drop for …`) it stops compiling, with the same error you get here.

Your solutions here are:

- if the MRE matches the actual code, don't bother preparing the statement, that's only useful if you have multiple queries
- explicitly `drop()` the statement once you're done with it
- or have it live in its own block, so its drop scope is shorter than the function

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have another question: If l24 is commented out, it works. Isn't there a default `drop() `executed to clean `Statement` ? If there is, shouldn't we have the same problem (about moving during active borrowing)?

Comment: @ccheneson no there is no default `drop()` because "trivial" types have no cleanup to perform (they're just memory on the stack so that goes away with the stackframe), so there is no semantic impact which could be linked to that cleanup, thus they are "dead" as soon as their last use ends.

Answer (score 4):

This reason for this is given in the error message:

```
14 | }
   | - borrow might be used here, when `stmt` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `Statement`
```

Calling `prepare()` on a `Transaction` (which is funneled through to `Connection` via a auto-deref) gives you a `Statement<'conn>`. In other words, `Statement` borrows the underlying `Connection` with lifetime `'conn`. That borrow of `Connection` depends on `Transaction`, because it was the auto-deref from `Transaction` that gave us a borrow on `Connection`.

Whenever a `Statement` is dropped, it uses its borrow of `Connection` to [clean up behind it](https://github.com/rusqlite/rusqlite/blob/e2af87f7470bfc83f30a9dc83ccea12617b1d833/src/statement.rs#L842-L848). This is where the problem arises: Your `stmt` is automatically dropped at the end of the scope, after `tx.commit().unwrap()`. Meanwhile `.commit()` takes ownership of `self`, so `Transaction` is moved away. But the `Drop` implementation of `Statement` requires the borrow of `Transaction` to be alive, so it can execute on its borrow of `Connection`; so an error occurs.

You can fix this by simply introducing an inner scope as you did, or by manually `drop(stmt)` after using it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had to read several times but it makes sense :)